# Using LibVpx on Android

Tags: android, webm

I have to make use of libVpx in Android, i searched on google and other forum following is my understanding and wanted to confirm,

1 -- http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html
     -- This site says, version 2.3.3+ onwards android platform, supports vp8, does that mean, if i target my application only above and this platform ?
     -- it also says, Coder is there but encoder is not there, can anyone throw me light, how can i make use of WebM encoder if i wanted to compress raw buffer using libvpx

2 -- It seems, i needs to integrate this library in my project, by making use of NDK, if i want to compress and decompress video data using WebM format or there would be any API in MediaPlayer to make use of this codec

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for looking at this,

i am able to compile it and integrate it, Makesure you should get the Libvpx 1.x.y version, which compiles easily for the Android platform...